# JS Errors because of proxy_ajp

Tags: http, proxy, tomcat6, ajp

We have an application running on tomcat6 with apache 2.2.16 and we have proxy_ajp enabled on port 80 that routes via ajp module. We also have an HTTP connector on port 9090.

Accessing the application using port 9090 works fine. When we access using port 80, we start getting JS errors on different pages of the application.

Can anyone point out what could be the possible cause of these JS errors? Is it related to proxy_ajp? If yes, how can we resolve it?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. Using latest AJP module version did the trick for us.